# Communicating with Arduino Serial

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I am trying to communicate with my Arduino over the USB port by using Serial:

```
int previous;
int current = 0;
void turnOn(int pinNumber){
  previous = current;
  current = pinNumber;
  if(previous!=0){
    digitalWrite(previous, LOW);
    digitalWrite(current, HIGH);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(current, HIGH);
  }

}
void setup(){
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.write(1);
}
void loop(){
  delay(1);
  if(Serial.available()>0){
  switch(Serial.read()){
    case 0:
      turnOn(8);
      break;
    case 1:
      turnOn(9);
      break;
    case 2:
       turnOn(10);
       break;
    default:
        Serial.println(Serial.read());
      }
  }  
}
```

I am trying so that if I send a 0 the rightmost LED will light up, if I send 1, the middle one will and if I send a 2 the leftmost will. However when I send 0,1 or anything else it prints a -1 meaning the default switch has been triggered. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
void loop(){
  if (Serial.available()) {
    char input = Serial.read();

    if(input == '0'){
       turnOn(8);
    }else if(input == '1'){
       turnOn(9);
    }else if(input == '2'){
       turnOn(10);
    }
  }
}
```

Tell me if it works or not then we can proceed :)

Comment: The reason your code didn't work was because the numbers you compared weren't really numbers in the ASCII Table. So you should put them inside quotes indicating that you want to compare the characters literally. If you want to compare numbers, then you should catch for the numbers 48,49,50, which are '0', '1', '2' in the ASCII Table.